# String replacement in python is replacing the entire string

Tags: python-3.x, string

When I do the string replacement I am getting an error. For example: my string is `my_string = '15:15'`. I want to replace `15` which is after the colon to `30`. For example I need `'15:30'`. When I try to do the string replace it's working fine for all other values for example, `'09:15'`, `'09:20'`.

I have tried:

```
my_string = '15:15'
my_new_string = my_string.replace(my_string[-2:], '30')

my_string = '15:15'
my_new_string = my_string.replace(my_string[-2:], '30')
```

What I am expecting is `15:30` but my actual output is `30:30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_new_string = my_string.replace(my_string[-2:],'30')` gets you `30:30`, because you are replacing all occurrences of `15` -> `15:15` will become `30:30`.

You could use `str.split` and `str.format` to get your new string:

```
my_string = '15:15'

my_new_string = '{}:{}'.format(my_string.split(':')[0], '30')

print(my_new_string)
```

Prints:

```
15:30
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior. Look at what the arguments for `str.replace()` mean:

> ```
> replace(...)
>     S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string
>
>     Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring
>     old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
>     given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
> ```

It does not replace a substring, rather all occurrences of what you pass as the first parameter.

By calling `my_string.replace(my_string[-2:], '30')` you're essentially calling `'15:15'.replace('15', '30')` -- which will replace all occurrences of "15" by "30" so you'll end up with `'30:30'`.

If you want to replace the last two characters, reverse your logic: keep everything up to the last two characters and then add the '30' string you want at the end:

```
my_new_string = my_string[:-2] + '30'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `my_string[-2:]` you are getting the string '15:'. Then when you substitute the function `string.replace` replaces all occurrences of 15: with 3, giving you 3030.

Instead, you can use `my_string[2:]` to get the string ':15' and replace it with ':30'. If you don't include the colon, then you will replace both occurrences of 15 and get '30:30'

```
my_new_string = my_string.replace(my_string[:-2], ':30')
```